# Vyatta DHCP relay is not relaying replies correctly in bridge

Tags: networking, firewall, dhcp

I have DHCP server (dnsmasq) on LAN network that has IP 192.168.255.2/16. Now I've created bridge on Vyatta that combines LAN and WLAN networks. Both NICs are on promiscuous mode in ESXi.

If I put test server on WLAN network that sends DHCP request then packets go through Vyatta bridge to LAN network and dnsmasq replies as expected. Reply goes to Vyatta box and then nothing. Test machine in WLAN network doesn't receive the reply. I can see the reply with Vyatta box when monitoring with tcpdump.

All machines are virtual and running on same physical ESXi host machine. If I put that same test machine on LAN network everything works. All networks are in own VLANs and ESXi handles tagging in NICs.

Is Vyatta's DHCP relay server broken somehow or am I missing some option/firewall/nat rule?

Vyatta config:

```
firewall {
    all-ping enable
    broadcast-ping disable
    ipv6-receive-redirects disable
    ipv6-src-route disable
    ip-src-route disable
    log-martians enable
    name drop-all {
        default-action drop
    }
    receive-redirects disable
    send-redirects enable
    source-validation disable
    syn-cookies enable
}
interfaces {
    bridge br0 {
        address 192.168.255.1/16
        aging 300
        hello-time 2
        max-age 20
        priority 0
        stp true
    }
    ethernet eth5 {
        bridge-group {
            bridge br0
        }
        description WLAN
        duplex auto
        hw-id 00:0c:29:60:1d:1b
        smp_affinity auto
        speed auto
    }
    ethernet eth6 {
        bridge-group {
            bridge br0
        }
        description LAN
        duplex auto
        hw-id 00:0c:29:60:1d:11
        smp_affinity auto
        speed auto
    }
    loopback lo {
    }
}
nat {
    source {
        rule 1 {
            description "Route traffic from LAN to Internet"
            destination {
                address !192.168.0.0/16
            }
            outbound-interface eth4
            source {
                address 192.168.0.0/16
            }
            translation {
                address masquerade
            }
        }
    }
}
service {
    dhcp-relay {
        interface br0
        relay-options {
            hop-count 10
            max-size 576
            port 67
            relay-agents-packets forward
        }
        server 192.168.255.2
    }
}
system {
    config-management {
        commit-revisions 20
    }
    console {
        device ttyS0 {
            speed 9600
        }
    }
    host-name lan-internet-nat
    login {
        user vyatta {
            authentication {
                encrypted-password ****************
            }
            level admin
        }
    }
    ntp {
        server fi.pool.ntp.org {
        }
    }
    package {
        auto-sync 1
        repository community {
            components main
            distribution stable
            password ****************
            url http://packages.vyatta.com/vyatta
            username ""
        }
    }
    syslog {
        global {
            facility all {
                level notice
            }
            facility protocols {
                level debug
            }
        }
    }
    time-zone GMT
}
```

- Vyatta 6.5R1 64 bit
- VMware ESXi 5.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable "Forged transmits" in ESXi NICs and removed DHCP relay server in Vyatta.

Comment: Hello I can't say I totally understand here but I am in a situation where vyatta handling a vpn with tunnel up doesn't seem to send the replies back to the originator of the ping. my settings, config, nat config and tcpdumps are available here http://pastie.org/9467922